# how to bring the cpu usage down when FFMPEG is making multi-bitrate videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to provide a website operating like Youtube.
To provide a facility for my users to upload their video on my server with multiple-bitrate through FFMPEG.
But when the FFMPEG is making multibitrate video files from the single video the server cpu usage is used to the maximum.
This means even I use the strongest cpu in the market just a few people can upload their videos.
So please advise me how to bring the cpu usage down when FFMPEG is making multi-bitrate videos.

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer is, if you're using Linux or similar, use the `nice` command when launching ffmpeg.

You use `nice` with any standard command and it adjusts the CPU priority of the command.

So if you're currently using

```
ffmpeg -i uploaded.mpg -vcodec copy  out1.mpg
```

(Except obviously, with more interesting arguments), 
You can just do

```
nice ffmpeg -i uploaded.mpg -vcodec copy  out1.mpg
```

.

Edit: I have seen you're using **Windows Server 2008**.

On Windows, the substitute for the `nice` command is to use the `START` command with options.

It would be worth reading this page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx

So you can use something like:

```
start /wait /low /b  ffmpeg [your arguments here]
```

- `/wait` means start the command at the end, and wait until it's finished.  Otherwise it will launch ffmpeg and return immediately - possibly starting another copy of ffmpeg to create an alternative bitrate, if you've built a loop like that.
- `/low` is the bit that says run the process at a low priority
- `/b` means don't open a command prompt window, which you won't need on your server.

**BUT**

Those are probably not the BEST answer.  The best answer is going to be to do the video processing on another server (or servers). You'll need to share a database and disk storage. When someone uploads a video, it'll need to be flagged for conversion. Then your render farm can pick off the rendering tasks one by one, saving to disk and updating the database with the available bitrates.

Separating the rendering off like this has two advantages:

1. It means that your web-server is not bogged down with processing video and so remains responsive to the users
2. You can add more servers to do the rendering if you like (or use cloud services).

That comes with a chunk of work though.